# Second display stretched/distorted

Tags: display, hardware, mac-mini, screen

[image]

The photo and the title pretty much say it all. I've played with all the display settings on both the Mac and the new monitor but it continues to show the display stretched instead of adding more screen real-estate.

It does appear normal if I unplug the smaller screen on the left.

How do I fix this? It's hurting my eyes?

```
Mac mini (Late 2014)
Big Sur 11.3
Processor: 3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7
Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Startup Disk: Mac HD
Graphics: Intel Iris 1536 MB
```

New Screen Specs:

[image]

Comment: We need more precise spec on the screen[s]. A lot of older computers can't cope with ultra-wide displays. [You really need to fix your colour profiling too. That would drive me more nuts than the resolution ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - I added screen spec. Does that help?

Comment: I';m wondering if it is an artifact of the aspect ratio a 21:9 aspect ratio at 2560 x 1080 is more suitable for TV/Movies. Heck I have a 27-inch Dell display with 2560 x 1440 resolution and yours is wider and has lower vertical resolution. I'd be surprised if it *wasn't* stretched. One thing you could try is SwitchResX which gives you very detailed control of the display settings. It might fix your issue and it is free to try...

Comment: Do you have the displays set to mirror each other (System Preferences -> Displays)? When your displays are in mirror mode, all secondary displays copy the main display, and necessarily stretch the output to fit their own aspect ratio. You can either change the aspect ration of the secondary display to match the primary display (which will fix the stretching, but leave a black border on the edges of the larger screen), or you can turn off mirroring, in which case the secondary monitor will become an extension of the primary desktop and the system will adjust everything to scale correctly.

Comment: @TedWrigley - it stretched in every scale and both using mirroring and not mirroring. i ended up returning the monitor and ordering a new one that's bigger but the same aspaect ratio.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce Could you add your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted? This will show other people that you could fix your issue and will help others that have a similar issue.

Comment: @jaume - "replace the monitor" is a non answer. the issue wasn't resolved. marking it as resolved just gives moderators an excuse to mark similar questions as duplicates. the question will remain unresolved.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I fully get your point, and I agree that an answer detailing a hardware or software tweak would surely be more useful, but replacing something that doesn't work as intended is, in my view, a valid answer. Moreover, even if someone provided a working answer in the future, since you have returned the monitor, you wouldn't be able to test it, so this question will most probably remain unresolved, **forever**, although your issue is solved.